# lesspipe error every new terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

Everytime I open a new terminal session, there's an error that greets me:

```
/usr/bin/lesspipe: 1: /usr/bin/lesspipe: basename: not found
/usr/bin/lesspipe: 295: [: =: unexpected operator
junjie@Amamangi:~$
```

They were not there when I installed this OS some days ago.. and I believe this was a by-product of something I installed. The first time I saw them, I just ignored them because I was busy, until OCD attacked me today.

I'm new in Ubuntu and I hope someone can point me in the right direction so I can remove this eyesore.

Comment: Does `basename --version` work? `basename` is part of the coreutils package, so you could try reinstalling that if the binary has been deleted

Comment: @steeldriver nope, it doesn't. Terminal says `The program 'basename' is currently not installed.`

Comment: Then try reinstalling the coreutils package - either from Software Center or from the terminal using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `basename` program has gone missing: you should be able to restore it by reinstalling the `coreutils` package, either from Software Center or from the terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```